# How can we convert HTML file / elements to JSON format in react-native

Tags: html, json, react-native

Developing sample application in react-native, I am getting the response in html format. How do I convert the html response to JSON format in react-native.

This is what I get exactly in the response

```
"content": "<!doctype html>\r\n<html>\r\n<head>\r\n<style>\r\n#ac-wrapper {\r\n    position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; background: rgba(255,255,255,.6); z-index: 1001;\r\n}\r\n.region{\r\n    color: #fff; font-weight: bold; text-transform: capitalize;\r\n}\r\n.city{\r\n    color: #fff;\r\n}\r\n.no-margin{\r\n    margin:0px;\r\n}\r\n#popup{\r\n    width: 555px; height: 230px; background: #0B6390; border: 1px solid #0B6390; box-shadow: #64686e 0px 0px 3px 3px;\r\n    -moz-box-shadow: #64686e 0px 0px 3px 3px; -webkit-box-shadow: #64686e 0px 0px 3px 3px; position: relative; top: 150px;\r\n}\r\n.button, .button:hover{\r\n    width:100%; background:#fff; color:#000 !important; font-weight: bold;\r\n}\r\n</style>\r\n</head>\r\n\r\n<body>\r\n<center>\r\n<div id=\"ac-wrapper\">\r\n  <div id=\"popup\">\r\n    <h2 class=\"region\">Select Your Region</h2>\r\n    </br>\r\n    <h3 class=\"city\" >Choose Your Nearest City</h3>\r\n    <br>\r\n      <div class=\"col-sm-6\">\r\n          <a href=\"{{store url=\"\"}}vizag\" target=\"_blank\">\r\n              <button class=\"button\">Visakhapatnam</button>\r\n           </a>             \r\n     </div>\r\n      <div class=\"col-sm-6\">\r\n          <a href=\"{{store url=\"\"}}hyd\" target=\"_blank\">\r\n              <button class=\"button\">Hyderabad</button>\r\n           </a>             \r\n     </div>\r\n  </div>\r\n</div>\r\n</center>\r\n\r\n<script type=\"text/javascript\">\r\nfunction PopUp(){\r\n        document.getElementById('ac-wrapper').style.display=\"none\"; \r\n}\r\n</script>\r\n</body>\r\n\r\n</html>"
```

Comment: You'd need to parse the HTML, extract the data that you care about from it (I've no idea what sort of data that is, expressing it as a single line of JavaScript encoded HTML makes it more-or-less unreadable), put it in a JavaScript data structure, then stringify it to JSON. Large chunks of that are either "too broad" or a stackoverflow question or "unclear" about what precisely you want the output to be.

Comment: could you give me the sample . If i using parse it's not working yet

Comment: No. See my note about being "too broad".

Comment: "if i using parse it's not working yet"...what kind of parse? Obviously JSON.parse will not work because the data is not JSON. You need something which will parse HTML and allow you then to traverse it easily and take bits from it. jQuery can do that, for example. I'm sure there are plenty of other options too if you search. Then once you can extract the bits you want from the HTML, then you can make it into a JS object, and then you can stringify it to make it into JSON. Those are the steps you need to go through. All of them individually can be researched and examples found online already.

Comment: Do some basic research and make an attempt, please. This is not a free do-my-research, write-my-code or even do-my-thinking service. We give our free time, and in return we expect at least some evidence of your own time having been spent first. We will _help_ you to solve your problem, not _solve it for you_. If you require someone to do all the work on your behalf, you will need to pay someone (not us). From your reputation score so far I would hope you have a good understanding of how this site works, by now.

Comment: in React-native jQuery is not working right??

Comment: That wasn't my point - my point was to go and do some simple research for yourself. (Although, I would guess jQuery doesn't technically require the DOM to be present in order to parse a string of HTML into a traversable object, but I could be wrong. Heck, why not try it and see where you get to?)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert HTML to JSON in react-native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53974408/convert-html-to-json-in-react-native)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this library: https://github.com/andrejewski/himalaya

```
import {parse} from 'himalaya'
const html = '<html/>' //your html goes here
const json = parse(html)
console.log(json)
```