# Convert HTML to JSON in react-native

Tags: javascript, html, json, react-native

I want to convert the HTML I received from a network request to JSON so I can easily read the values.
*If there is a way to read values straight from HTML please let me know in a comment*
I have found this library: https://github.com/andrejewski/himalaya
but when I try to run the example in my app I get the error `Cannot read property prototype of undefined` so I assume this library doesn't work in react-native because it contains a core Node JS module.
This was the code:

```
import {parse} from 'himalaya'
const html = this.state.html
const json = parse(html)
console.log('', json)
```

Some example html could be:

```
<div class='post post-featured'>
  <p>Himalaya parsed me...</p>
  <!-- ...and I liked it. -->
</div>
```

The expected output of this html is:

```
[{
  type: 'element',
  tagName: 'div',
  attributes: [{
    key: 'class',
    value: 'post post-featured'
  }],
  children: [{
    type: 'element',
    tagName: 'p',
    attributes: [],
    children: [{
      type: 'text',
      content: 'Himalaya parsed me...'
    }]
  }, {
    type: 'comment',
    content: ' ...and I liked it. '
  }]
}]
```

Is there another way/library to convert HTML to JSON in react native?

Comment: if you provide the code you have written I might be able to help. It looks like you need to use `window.himalaya.parse(html)` on the client side.

Comment: I added the code (I took it straight from the docs)

Comment: Do you have access to modify the response of the server?

Comment: Do you have some html that you are trying to convert?

Comment: I don't have access to modify the server's response, this is a 3rd party api.

Comment: The html has some sensative data so I dont feel comfortable sharing it. I'll edit the question to include some example html

Comment: see working answer below @joshkmartinez

Comment: I'll check it out

Comment: I am in react-native, not react, your answer is in react

Comment: Did you delete your answer @PaulFitzgerald ? I don't see it anymore

Comment: Could you provide the stack trace of the error? It could yield the position where the error is thrown in the library's source code to better pinpoint and understand the error.

Comment: There is no stack trace in the error code, all I know is that when I delete the code the error goes away, so it has to be from the library

Comment: Both the source code of the library and the transpiled JavaScript don't use the `new` keyword or try to access the `prototype` object of a function/object. The library also doesn't seem to use any other dependencies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no issue in using the package you have mentioned in React Native. Everything works as expected given you have followed all required steps:

Install `himalaya`:

```
cd project_dir
npm install himalaya
```

Add the required `import` at the top of your file:

`import {parse} from 'himalaya';`

Set the `html` property in `state` somewhere in your code, *before* parsing the HTML result:

`this.setState = { html: '<div>Example HTML content</div>' };`

Convert the HTML into JSON with `parse` object:

```
const html = this.state.html;
const json = parse(html);
alert(JSON.stringify(json));
```

You can check the code above works as expected in [this Snack](https://snack.expo.io/@siavas/stackoverflow-53974408).

Comment: Interesting. It's great that the library works in React Native, though I don't understand how it would try to access `prototype`. It apparently is associated with that specific line, but I do hope this works!

Comment: @Arct indeed the error specified in the question does not seem related, but the problem might have been caused by some misplaced code. I hope the linked Snack will guide the OP into getting the additional lines in the right place, and potentially other people googling this very problem to find a quick tutorial.

Comment: I guess that's true. I'm curious as to what exactly is causing the error, but it could honestly be anything. However, your answer has proved that the library works, which is great. The example is a great way to gather some example code :) Hope the OP finds this useful!

Comment: I figured it out! I upgraded expo to v31.0.0 and it started working. Thanks!